# How to execuete insert data with query function in oci

Tags: sql, oracle, codeigniter, plsql

I am working in oci8 in codeigniter. I need to execute query like

```
INSERT INTO medi_appointment (ref_emp_doc_id, appointment_time, ref_emp_patient_id, ref_emp_patient_type, appointment_date, appointment_status, status, summary) 
VALUES ('54', '132', '5', 'employee', TO_DATE('2022-04-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), '0', '1', 'testing summary')`
```

Column appointment_date is date format. When i insert data with codeigniter db->insert then query return like this

```
INSERT INTO medi_appointment (ref_emp_doc_id, appointment_time, ref_emp_patient_id, ref_emp_patient_type, appointment_date, appointment_status, status, summary) 
VALUES ('54', '132', '5', 'employee', 'TO_DATE(''2022-04-22'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'')', '0', '1', 'testing summary')`
```

This column 'TO_DATE(''2022-04-22'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'')' is got string but not to execute TO_DATE function execute.

how can i solve it??

Comment: The insert works fine in dbFiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=617617a682aebcaba6a4ff5265db2e09

Comment: Don’t quote the function call.